# Rewrite Mathematica output in Python

Tags: python, numpy, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I want to convert the piecewise-function output of a calculation in Mathematica into Python. Taking inspiration from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85817/prepare-mathematica-output-to-be-parsed-in-python/85818) page for the Mathematica->Python conversion and [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/how-can-i-plot-piece-wise-defined-function-in-some-easily-accessed-open-source-t) page for writing piecewise functions, I have

```
from numpy import linspace, vectorize, array
from numpy import arctan, log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.parsing.mathematica import parse

def fun(x,a,b,c):
    # string inside parse('') is my mathematica output
    if a == 0:
        out = parse('a (-I b + x) ArcTan[(b - a)/c]')
    else:
        out = parse('4 c a^2 Log[c^2 + (x - a)^2]')
    return out

a = 0.17
b = 0.44
c = 0.29
x = linspace(0,50,int(1e3))

vfun = vectorize(fun)
y = vfun(x,a,b,c)
yp = 4*c*a**2*log(c**2 + (x - a)**2)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'.-')
plt.title('mathematica -> python conversion')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,yp,'.-')
plt.title('expected')

plt.show()
```

The plot looks like:

[image]

whereas it should be:

[image]

Have I done something wrong when converting Mathematica to Python? Or is there a problem when assigning numerical values to `a`, `b`, and `c`? (Note that this is a MWE, and the Mathematica code that I want to convert is much longer and complicated than what is shown above.)

Comment: Could you maybe also show what you expect to see or what the initial Mathematica output was? For example you could plot also in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty solution:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica
from sympy import symbols

def fun(x, a, b, c):
    # string inside parse('') is my mathematica output
    if a == 0:
        out = mathematica('a (-I b + x) ArcTan[(b - a)/c]')
    else:
        out = mathematica('4 c a^2 Log[c^2 + (x - a)^2]')
    return out

aa = 0.17
bb = 0.44
cc = 0.29
II = 1
xx = np.linspace(0, 50, int(1e3))

x, a, b, c, I = symbols('x, a, b, c, I')

fun1 = fun(x, a, b, c)
fun2 = fun1.subs({a: aa, c: cc})
print(fun2.evalf())

y_list = []

for item in xx:
    y_list.append(fun2.subs({x:item}).evalf())

print(y_list[:10])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xx, y_list,'.-')
plt.title('mathematica -> python conversion')
plt.show()
```

I will explain it later how all of this works.

#### Update

As you may see, when `a == 0`, the function is `0`, you need to check that.

When you use `mathematica`, the type of `fun1` is a `sympy` function (`sympy.core.mul.Mul`), that's why you have to use `symbols` and `fun1.subs()` and `fun2.evalf()`, in other words, you need to know who to use the basic functions of `sympy`.

The way you evaluate a function in order to plot it, well, you use a list:

```py
y_list = []

for item in xx:
    y_list.append(fun2.subs({x:item}).evalf())
```

By the way, I am using `sympy` version 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier solution is using `eval`. Now I know `eval` is very dangerous but most of the time when it takes input from user, but here the input is already defined for us.
Now onto the answer.
You are not getting the expected output because your vectorized array does not contain any floats but only contains output from mathematica's parser which return unevaluated string, so we can use `.evalf()` as answer given by @David, `lambdify()` which uses `eval()` internally or we can directly use `eval()`.
Here is the documentation of the methods used : https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html

```
from numpy import linspace, vectorize, array
from numpy import arctan, log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.parsing.mathematica import MathematicaParser

def fun(x,a,b,c):
    obj = MathematicaParser()
    if a == 0:
        out = obj.parse('a (-I b + x) ArcTan[(b - a)/c]')
    else:
        out = obj.parse('4 c a^2 Log[c^2 + (x - a)^2]')

    return out

a = 0.17
b = 0.44
c = 0.29
x = linspace(0,50,int(1e3))
yp = 4*c*a**2*log(c**2 + (x - a)**2)
vfun = vectorize(fun)
y = vfun(x,a,b,c)
#Here y is a type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> containing 1000 <class 'numpy.str_'>
#['4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)' '4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)'
#'4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)' '4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)'
#'4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)' '4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)'
#'4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)' '4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)'
#....
y = eval(y[0]) #y[0] is '4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)'
#When we evaluate y[0] we again get y as <class 'numpy.ndarray'> conatining 1000 <class 'numpy.float64'>
#Because x is <class 'numpy.ndarray'> it evaluates the first string over
#all the points in x.
#[-0.07309464 -0.07770262 -0.08110382 -0.0828403  -0.08263539 -0.08052339
#-0.07683235 -0.07203573 -0.06659307 -0.06086366 -0.05509179 -0.04942739
#-0.04395413 -0.03871304 -0.03371924 -0.0289728  -0.02446552 -0.02018495
#.....
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y,'.-')
plt.title('mathematica -> python conversion')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,yp,'.-')
plt.title('expected')

plt.show()
```

Output :
 [image]

Comment: What sympy version are you using? I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'MathematicaParser'` when I run your code

Comment: @MedullaOblongata i'm using version  1.4 https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html. Also my python version is 3.7.3

Comment: thanks, I'm using sympy version 1.1.1 and have no way to upgrade. But I have copied the source code from https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/parsing/mathematica.html#mathematica, which seems to work.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata you could also try your original `from sympy.parsing.mathematica import parse` I switched it because it was not working for me, looking at it's source code it seems that it returns string which can also be evaluated using `eval()` it could be much better than copying the code from `MathematicaParser()`

Comment: yes I tried just using `sympy.parsing.mathematica.parse` and `eval`, but I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. The `eval` function gives `4 c a**2 Log[c**2+(x-a)**2]` instead of `4*c*a**2*log(c**2+(x-a)**2)`.

Comment: Different versions are a huge pain, I don't have any other solutions as of now, it's also hard for me to reproduce.  I guess your best bet would be to use source code or upgrade or implement other answer.

Comment: Nice, so it is possible to use `vectorize`, I didn't know that